# Why won't the dragon take my golden coin?

Tags: the-book-of-unwritten-tales

I'm at the point where I have the golden coin and have to give it to the dragon. The coin is already embossed but there is no possible interaction with the dragon.

According to the solutions I've found, this is supposed to be the next step.
So did I miss something? How can I pass this passage? I haven't been able to find a savegame online that is after this step either.

Comment: I cleaned up some of the grammar in your post. I wasn't quite sure what you meant by "not finding a savegame," I assume you meant that you searched on the internet and were unable to find a savegame that was past the point you are stuck. Please feel free to re-edit your question if I have misinterpreted your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, which is not quite obvious.

The short version, install the [JaWooD Patch](http://www.4players.de/4players.php/download_info/Downloads/Download/56313/The_Book_of_Unwritten_Tales/Patch_101_JoWooD_Version.html).

The long version, JaWooD once bought the distributionsrights, but [wasn't authorized](http://www.kingart.de/101015_bout_jowood.pdf) (german). However, they mixed a patched version with unpatched files, therefore such issues like mine described above happens. Luckily a patch exists.

Answer (score 0):

[This walkthrough](http://www.gameboomers.com/wtcheats/pcTt/TBoUT/TBoUT.htm) might help you, particularly this section:

> Dragon:   Use the map to go the Fiery Mountain at right of map.   Talk
>   to the lady transport dragon that carried MacGuffin and was released
>   by Ivo. She wants to be a feared dragon, a position usually held by
>   male dragons.   Nate will give her a starter gold coin for her hoard
>   and she will give the sword.
>
> Get the head of the lava bowl: Look at the lava bowl -headless metal
>   dragon. Check the hole where the head was located.   Check the
>   furnace. Take the stone bowl right of the furnace.   Check the coin
>   press machine left of the furnace.   Check the anvil and stone trough.
>   Take the pliers and hammer.   Take a glittery stone from the ground at
>   left.
>
> Pixies:     Remember where we saw a dragon's head. The pixie at the
>   altar was cleaning the sooty dragon's head. Pixies love shiny things.
>   Lay the stone on the anvil. Hammer about the anvil by clicking the
>   hammer on the anvil. The stone splits open to get stone with crystals.
>   Jump to the pixie mine. Go up until the once smoky passage and then
>   right. Go down to the altar. Give the stone with crystals to the pixie
>   cleaning the dragon's head. Take the stone dragon's head.  Take also
>   offering - gold nuggets from the altar.
>
> Make a gold coin: Jump back to the Fiery Mt. Use the dragon's head on
>   the hole of the lava bowl. Check the hatch of the lava bowl. Pull the
>   chain of the lava bowl to open the hatch and get lava inside the
>   furnace. In inventory, combine the stone bowl and gold nugget. Place
>   the stone bowl inside the furnace. Use the pliers on furnace to get
>   the stone bowl with melted gold. Use the melted gold on the gold press
>   at left. Look at press to get gold coin. Give the gold coin to the
>   dragon.

Comment: I already have a pressed/embossed gold coin, but the cursor isn't changing when hovering the dragon with the coin. I can't give the coin to the dragon.

Comment: Hm. That is strange, because it should work. :(